# Node.js / Socket.io raising Error at TCP.Onread

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, error-handling

I'm running a simple Node Instance which pushes data from Redis to the clients through Socket.io.

My Node Server crashes from time to time. And I've already spend hours in debugging, but I just can't find the problem.

It is not really predictable. Sometimes the instance runs just fine for 36 hours, sometime it crashes every minute.

I receive the following Error Message:

```
events.js:77
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:676:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:529:26)
```

This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer().listen(4000);


var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var redis = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis');
var sub = redis.createClient();
var sc = redis.createClient(); //active socket counter

//Subscribe to the Redis chat channel
sub.subscribe('chat');
sub.subscribe('total_spots');


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   //Grab message from Redis and send to client
   sub.on('message', function(channel, message){
       socket.send(message);
   });


    count++;
    sc.incr("sockets");

        socket.on('disconnect', function(socket){
        count--;
        sc.decr("sockets");
    })  


    socket.on("error", function(err){
       console.log(err);
       console.log("error");
    });
});
```

I would very much appreciate any tipps or ideas.

Thanks!